# How to ignore Dynamic island's inset/padding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, activitykit, dynamic-island

I'm searching how this app ignore dynamic island's default inset, to set a gray background to is's bottom area.
[some app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9l9w.png)
While I test every API AcitivityKit offer, I cant't extent my view to the inset.
[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD4CU.png)

I tried padding, contentMargins, none of these worked.

```
ActivityConfiguration(for: ONELiveActivityInfoAttributes.self) { context in
            // Lock screen
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading, priority: 0) {
                    // some view
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
                    // some view
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom, priority: 1) {
                    VStack {
                        Color.white
                    }.background(Color.white).padding(-100).offset(y: 10)
                }.contentMargins(.bottom, 3)
                
            } compactLeading: {

            } compactTrailing: {

            } minimal: {

            }
            .contentMargins(.all, 2, for: .expanded)
        }
```

Comment: Please try to use some tools to help you fix the English grammar in your StackOverflow questions. It will help the community who is willing to answer your questions.